# Merging Arrays into one Array and populate keys with same values

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I need to merge Arrays into one Array and replace $key with $values of the same array.

My Array looks like this:

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
  [city] => Berlin 
  ) 
  [1] => Array 
  ( 
  [city] => London
  ) 
  [2] => Array 
  ( 
  [city] => New York 
  )
  [3] => Array 
  ( 
  [city] => Vienna
  )
)
```

Desired result

```
Array 
( 
  [Berlin] => Berlin 
  [London] => London
  [New York] => New York 
  [Vienna] => Vienna
)
```

updates:
source looks like this:

````
$a = json_decode('[{"city":"Berlin"},{"city":"London"},{"city":"New York"}, {"city":"Vienna"}]', true);```
````

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, Iam, i try with call_user_func_array , array_walk_recursive, array_column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneliner is:

```
$newArray = array_column($yourArray, 'city', 'city');
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/bCj7L).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column` :

```
$res = array_column($array, 'city');
```

this will give you your result, but as key you will have integer values, to get the city also as key, check [@u_mulder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553888/u-mulder) answer

Comment: It will be just `[Berlin. London ...]` with numeric keys. Probably `array_column($array, 'city', 'city');` might do the job.

Comment: @u_mulder you are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

```php
$a = [['city' => 'Berlin'], ['city' => 'London']];
$b = [];

foreach ($a as $arr) $b[$arr['city']] = $arr['city'];

print_r($b);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [Berlin] => Berlin [London] => London )
```

Comment: this is on of the source how i got it, source is JSON and i if use json_decode this not works: [
{
"value": "0 800 nnn nnnn"
},
{
"value": "00 800-nnnnnnnn"
},
{
"value": "National (720)"
},
{
"value": "Vienna"
}
]

Comment: you can `$array = json_decode($json, true);` to convert it into array. the `true` is required.

Comment: [link]https://3v4l.org/oEBL9#v7.4.24

Comment: and second option https://3v4l.org/daJsf

Comment: missing `}`after `{"city":"New York"`

Comment: This is also works perfect, Thanks!!!, btw i updated links for missing "}"